# win8 Frame delegate

Tags: windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I have a frame which has a function that updates the frame when an event in another class is raised.
I have the class 'IRCClient' and 'MainFrame'. The IRCClient class has an event 'OnMessageRecvd', the MainFrame has a function 'HandleNewMessageReceived'. In the MainFrame class I have the variables 'CurrentServer' and 'CurrentChannel' to indicate what channel on what server is currently shown to the user.

Now, when I set the 'CurrentServer' and 'CurrentChannel' in the callback of a button, they have a value and all is fine. However, when the 'HandleNewMessageReceived' function is called by the 'OnMessageRecvd' event of IRCClient, the CurrentServer and CurrentChannel are both equal to any value (null) stated in the constructor of MainFrame.

Does anyone have an idea what the source of this behavior is? Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:
Below is the code, I've only posted the code in question (any function that uses the CurrentChannel and CurrentServer properties) and snipped away unrelated code.

```
// Main page, shows chat history.
public sealed partial class MainPage : LIRC.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
    private uint maxMessages;
    IRCClient ircc;
    IRCHistory irch;
    string CurrentServer, CurrentChannel;

    // Does all the setup for this class.
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ircc = App.ircc; // This is a global variable in the 'App' class.
        ircc.OnMessage += NewMessageReceived;

        irch = App.irch; // This is also a global variable in the 'App' class.
        currentChannel = currentServer = null;
    }

    // Restores the previous state.
    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        if (pageState != null)
        {
            if(pageState.ContainsKey("viewedChannel"))
            {
                // Retrieve required info.
                string[] viewedChannelTokens = (pageState["viewedChannel"] as string).Split('.');
                CurrentChannel = viewedChannelTokens[0];
                CurrentServer = viewedChannelTokens[1];

                // If the saved channel or server got corrupt
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentChannel) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentServer))
                {
                    // Check if a channel is open, if so, select it.
                    *snip* // Non-relevant code.
                }

                // Clear and load required history.
                ClearHistory();
                if(CurrentServer != null && CurrentChannel != null)
                    LoadHistory(CurrentServer, CurrentChannel);
            }
        }

        // Create buttons that switch to a channel
        *Snip* // Calls AddChannelButton
    }

    // Creates a button that, when clicked, causes the ChatHistoryView to display the ChannelHistory.
    void AddChannelButton(string Server, string Channel)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Content = Channel + "\n" + Server;
        btn.Width = 150;

        // A function to switch to another channel.
        btn.Click += (e, s) =>
        {
            ClearHistory(); // Clears the ChatHistoryVi.ew field.
            LoadHistory(Server, Channel); // Does the actual loading of the channel history

            CurrentChannel = Channel;
            CurrentServer = Server;
        };

        ChannelBar.Children.Add(btn);
    }

    // The function that is called by the IRCClient.OnMessageRecv event.
    public void NewMessageReceived(ref DataWriter dw, IRCServerInfo ircsi, IRCClient.RecvMessage recvmsg)
    {
        if (ircsi.Name == CurrentServer && CurrentChannel == recvmsg.recipient)
        {
            AddMessage(DateTimeToTime(DateTime.UtcNow), recvmsg.author, recvmsg.message);
        }
    }
}

// Responsible for creating, managing and closing connections.
public class IRCClient
{
    // A structure that describes a message.
    public struct RecvMessage
    {
        public string author;   // Nickname
        public string realName;
        public string ipAddress;
        public string recipient; // Indicates in what channel or private converstion.
        public string message;   // The actual message
    };

    // Describes how a function that handles a message should be declared.
    public delegate void MessageHandler(ref DataWriter dw, IRCServerInfo ircsi, RecvMessage msg);

    // Gets raised/called whenever a message was received.
    public event MessageHandler OnMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is happening from what you said, but if the variables are set to the values you set in the constructor when you check them - it means that either you have not changed them yet by the time you are expecting them to be changed or you set the value of some other variables instead of the ones you thought you had.

These are only guesses though and you can't expect more than guesses without showing your code.